# AnimatedContainer - How do I expand only one and the rest stay below?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

So there's something I'm working on and I want to have a list of these "capsules" (rounded rectangle containers). When the user taps on any given one of them, it expands to the full screen, while the rest stay on a lower layer and don't do anything.

[image]

I'm using AnimatedContainer and GestureDetector to change their state. When there's only one, it works perfectly for what I want to do. Meanwhile, as soon as I add more in a Column, because it's a single Widget I coded inside a GestureDetector with a single boolean, they all open at the same time. And I understand that even if I code them separately, it will basically just push the surrounding ones out of the way, not open above them. How would I deal with this?

[image]

I tried searching this and couldn't find anything helpful. Hopefully the answer to this will help future projects too.

````
bool chatCapsuleTapped = false;
bool hasFullSize = false;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget _chatCapsuleAnimation() {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            chatCapsuleTapped = !chatCapsuleTapped;
            hasFullSize = true;
          });
        },
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          width: !chatCapsuleTapped ? 350 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: !chatCapsuleTapped ? 75 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          //color: !chatCapsuleTapped ? Colors.grey.withOpacity(1) : Colors.grey,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: !chatCapsuleTapped ? Colors.grey.shade500 : Colors.grey.shade300,
            borderRadius: !chatCapsuleTapped ? BorderRadius.circular(40) : BorderRadius.circular(0),
          ),
          child: !chatCapsuleTapped ? Container(child: Container(),) : Container(),
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _chatCapsuleAnimation(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
````

Comment: Is an HeroAnimation an option for you ? If not I think the way to go is to use an overlay (which is basically what the HeroWidget does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Hero`:

Place each widget inside a `Hero` widget, assign it a tag based on the `index`.

Then have a Full-Screen page, which contains the bigger version of the widget, but with the same tag as of the tapped item.

Sample Grabbed from [here](https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/examples/_animation/basic_hero_animation/main.dart), you can paste it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter)

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Basic Hero Animation'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              children: List<Widget>.generate(5, (index) {
        return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        title: const Text('Full-Screen Page'),
                      ),
                      body: Container(
                        child: Hero(
                          // TAG should be same as the tapped item's index
                          tag: index.toString(),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            child: Container(
                                color: Colors.grey[(index + 1) * 100]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Hero(
              // Assigning tag of item as its index in the list
              tag: index.toString(),
              child: Container(
                  height: 200, color: Colors.grey[(index + 1) * 100]),
            ));
      }))),
    );
  }
}
```

I've put the destination page within the scope of the main file for simplicity, but you can make a seperate Widget and accept `index` as parameter for the Bigger `Hero`'s tag